# Get verbatim file content into exif data trought hyperref

Tags: hyperref, verbatim, brackets, external-files, metadata

#### The goal

I have the following external `main.bib` file containing:

```
@book{fauve2023TheSuperBook,
 title = {The Super Book},
 author = {Fauve},
 publisher = {MadPublisher},
 year = {3 June 2023}
}
```

I whant to put it content into an exif entry called `bibtex`. This block code should then became a metada.

#### MWE

In this order, I use the following MWE

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sverb}
\usepackage{catchfile}


\newcommand{\importverbatim}[2][]{%
  \CatchFileDef{\temp}{#2}{\endlinechar=-1}%
  \ifx\temp\empty
    \def\importedcontent{}%
  \else
    \def\importedcontent{\temp}%
  \fi
  \hypersetup{#1={bibtex=\importedcontent}}%
}

\importverbatim[pdfinfo]{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

You can cite this work with the following Bib\TeX block:


\verbinput{\jobname.bib}


\end{document}
```

#### The result

Then, when I inspect the metadata with `exiftool` i get:

```
exiftool main.pdf
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.16
File Name                       : main.pdf
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 9.1 KiB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:06:14 14:31:45+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2023:06:14 14:31:46+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:06:14 14:31:45+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PDF
File Type Extension             : pdf
MIME Type                       : application/pdf
PDF Version                     : 1.5
Linearized                      : No
Page Mode                       : UseOutlines
Page Count                      : 1
Creator                         : LaTeX with hyperref
Bibtex                          : @bookfauve2023TheSuperBook,title = The Super Book,author = Fauve,publisher = MadPublisher,year = 3 June 2023
Producer                        : xdvipdfmx (20200315)
Create Date                     : 2023:06:14 14:31:45+03:00
```

##### The deception

As you see in the `Bibtex` line, their is two main unwanted behaviors.

1. All the Curly brackets was deleted. It like if LaTeX interpreted them instead of just coping them in a verbatim way. This point is the most unwanted one.
2. The new line was deleted. Well… I don’t know if exif standard allow new lines, but if yes, it would be highly preferable to get a multiline rendering. If not, no matter.

#### The question

So, how to just put the content of the external file into the exif value data without interpreting it, without deleting the curly brackets, and ideally (but not necessary) remain the newlines?

Comment: you can keep the braces if  you change their catcode when reading: ``\CatchFileDef{\temp}{#2}{\endlinechar=-1 \catcode`\{=12\catcode`\}=12}%``

Comment: One correction.  None of the data listed is EXIF data.  All EXIF data is metadata, but not all metadata is EXIF data.  EXIF data can exist exist in a pdf but it is rare, goes against the specs, and is non-standard.  You should use the command in [ExifTool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) to see all tags, including duplicates, and the groups they belong to.